# How to set Bluetooth Device adress and name in android BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to set device name and address of `Android Bluetooth LE` device.

the class `BluetoothDevice` provides getter methods for name and address like

```
BluetoothDevice device;

device.getName();
device.getAddress();
```

But there is no visible constructor or setter methods for device name and address like

```
BluetoothDevice device;

device.setName();
device.setAddress();
```

Please guide how to get rid of the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The address is STATIC allocated in produktion. You are not supposed to spoof it.
In the Advertising package you can set a Name.

Comment: Dear! Please a bit elaborate your words.